# In his July 1925 paper, how does Heisenberg solve the difference equation to get the first order amplitude as a function of $n$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

The question is about the paper *"Über quantentheoretische Umdeutung kinematischer und mechanischer Beziehungen."* by Werner Heisenberg (1925) (See e.g. [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01328377)).
The PDF-file containing the (german) paper can be found [here](http://www.psiquadrat.de/downloads/heisenberg1925.pdf).
A translation of the title and abstract can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20070927001602/http://dbserv.ihep.su/hist/owa/hw.part2?s_c=HEISENBERG%201925).

I don't understand how he arrives at equation (20)
$$a^2(n,n-1) = C\, n+ const.$$ from his quantum condition
$$C = |a(n,n+1)|^2 - |a(n,n-1)|^2$$ with $C = h/\pi m \omega_0$ (I suppose that's where he starts but I may be wrong). It seems very elementary but I don't get it. Shouldn't there be two independent constants?

And (maybe I should ask this in another question) does he omit the other terms in the quantum condition just because he's only considering the first order solution or is there a more general reason - I mean in "real" QM, $\langle n | X | n + \delta \rangle$ vanishes if $|\delta| \neq 1$ for the harmonic oscillator (doesn't it?) but he couldn't be aware of that in July 1925 ...

Comment: Link to abstract page?

Comment: http://www.psiquadrat.de/downloads/heisenberg1925.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use $A$ instead of $a^2$, just for notation convenience.
For $n$:
$$A(n,n-1)=n C +k$$
Now, for n+1:
$$A(n+1,n)=(n+1) C +k$$
Subtract the two expressions:
$$
A(n+1,n)-A(n,n-1)=(n+1) C +k -(n C +k)= C
$$

Comment: Isn't $A$ supposed to be symmetric according to $a_{-\alpha} = \bar{a_\alpha}$ on page 885 (between (13) and (14)), i.e. $A(n+1,n) = A(n,n+1)$?